# Python: what could be causing requests object to be losing attributes?

Tags: python, python-requests, tableau-api

I am trying to determine why the Response object I am returning is being handled differently by the same script when running it multiple times? When the script is successful, the response object is passed around as `<class 'requests.models.Response'>`, when it is unsuccessful, it loses all attributes and is passed around as `<type 'NoneType'>` and I am at a loss as to how that could be?

Additional details:

I am running a script that signs in and signs out of Tableau Server via their [API](https://onlinehelp.tableau.com/current/api/rest_api/en-us/REST/rest_api_ref.htm) using Python 2.7 and requests. The script is being run off an SSH connection to our databox, and I am getting some odd results.

If it is not successful on the 1st attempt to post a request, it will fail but takes anywhere from 2 attempts to 7 attempts before I reach that point.

The script:

```
import time
import requests
import sys
import xml.etree.ElementTree as ET


class TableauHook():

    def __init__(self):
        self.url = 'https://{server}.com/api/2.8/'
        self.username = 'username'
        self.password = 'password'
        self.name = 'datasource_name'
        self.auth_header = None
        self.sign_in = self._sign_in()


    def _sign_in(self):
        endpoint = 'auth/signin'
        payload = '<tsRequest><credentials name="{name}" password="{pw}" ><site contentUrl="" /></credentials></tsRequest>'.format(
            name=self.username, pw=self.password)
        # Request setup
        req = self.send_request(req_type='post', endpoint=endpoint, payload=payload)
        print('Returned req: ' + str(type(req)))


        if req.content:
            print('Sign in to Tableau: Success')
            response = ET.fromstring(req.content)

            # Parse and store request data
            self.token = response.find('.//t:credentials',
                                       namespaces={'t': "http://tableau.com/api"}).attrib['token']
            self.site_id = response.find('.//t:site',
                                         namespaces={'t': "http://tableau.com/api"}).attrib['id']
            self.auth_header = {'X-tableau-auth': self.token}

            print('Token: exists' )
            print('Site id: exists')
            print('Auth_header: exists' )
        else:
            print('Sign in to Tableau unsuccessful')


    def send_request(self, req_type, endpoint, payload=None, attempts=None):
        # Count attempts to send request
        if attempts == None:
            attempts = 1
        else:
            attempts = attempts

        if attempts > 20:
            sys.exit('Too many attempts made')

        print('\nAttempt: ' + str(attempts))
        print('Endpoint: ' + endpoint)
        # Send request/load response
        try:
            if req_type.upper() == 'POST':
                response = requests.post(self.url + endpoint, data=payload, headers=self.auth_header)
                print('Response: ' + str(type(response)))
                if type(response) == type(None):
                    print('Response is NoneType')
                    raise Exception('NoneType returned')
                return response
            elif req_type.upper() == 'GET':
                response = requests.get(self.url + endpoint, data=payload, headers=self.auth_header)
                print('Response: ' + str(type(response)))
                if type(response) == type(None):
                    raise Exception('NoneType returned')
                return response

        except Exception as e:
            print('Error: ' + str(e))
            print('Sleeping for 3 seconds...')
            time.sleep(3)
            attempts += 1
            print('Running send_request() again')
        self.send_request(req_type=req_type, endpoint=endpoint, payload=payload, attempts=attempts)



    def sign_out(self):
        endpoint = 'auth/signout'
        try:
            req = requests.post(self.url+endpoint, headers=self.auth_header)
        except Exception as e:
            print(e)
            time.sleep(3)
            req = requests.post(self.url + endpoint, headers=self.auth_header)
        print('Returned response: ' + str(type(req)))
        print(req)
        print('\n')

def main():
    hook = TableauHook()
    print('\nSigning out\n')
    hook.sign_out()


if __name__ == '__main__':
    main()
```

Here is the console output for 2 different attempts:

```
# First attempt to run the script
[user@databox directory]$ python TableauDBTest.py 

Attempt: 1
Endpoint: auth/signin
Response: <class 'requests.models.Response'>
Returned req: <class 'requests.models.Response'>
Sign in to Tableau: Success
Token: exists
Site id: exists
Auth_header: exists

Signing out

Returned response: <class 'requests.models.Response'>
<Response [204]>

# Run the script again, this time with different results
[user@databox directory]$ python TableauDBTest.py 

Attempt: 1
Endpoint: auth/signin
Error: ('Connection aborted.', error(104, 'Connection reset by peer'))
Sleeping for 3 seconds...
Running send_request() again

Attempt: 2
Endpoint: auth/signin
Response: <class 'requests.models.Response'>
Returned req: <type 'NoneType'>
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "TableauDBTest.py", line 115, in <module>
    main()
  File "TableauDBTest.py", line 109, in main
    hook = TableauHook()
  File "TableauDBTest.py", line 15, in __init__
    self.sign_in = self._sign_in()
  File "TableauDBTest.py", line 27, in _sign_in
    if req.content:
AttributeError: 'NoneType' object has no attribute 'content'
```

Thanks in advance for any thoughts on what might be causing this!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your `send_request` method is recursively calling `self.send_request`, but it's not returning the value; it's just ignoring it and then falling off the end of the function and returning `None`.

So, the simplest fix is to change the last line from this:

```
self.send_request(req_type=req_type, endpoint=endpoint, payload=payload, attempts=attempts)
```

… to this:

```
return self.send_request(req_type=req_type, endpoint=endpoint, payload=payload, attempts=attempts)
```

However, it would be a lot simpler to rewrite this as a loop instead of using recursion:

```
def send_request(self, req_type, endpoint, payload=None):
    for attempt in range(1, 21):
        print(etc.)
        try:
            stuff
            return response
        except blah blah:
            ...
    sys.exit('Too many attempts made')
```

Comment: Thanks, that is a much cleaner/effective way to do that. Eventually got the connection every time.

Could you explain how calling self.send_request() recursively would return `None` as it only returns on a success and would reach the recursive call on any error, until the success. Returning the recursive call would return any response from sending the request, including an error on the second. Unless I am totally missing something?

Comment: @AlexBowden Calling `self.send_request(…)` doesn't return `None`. The problem is that you're ignoring whatever it _does_ return. So, just like calling `print('\nAttempt: ' + str(attempts))` doesn't make your function return the result of that `print` function call, calling `self.send_request(…)` doesn't make your function return the result of that `self.send_request` function call. Your function just keeps going—and then it reaches the end of the function body without having returned, which, in Python, means it automatically returns `None`.